# How to make nib view to fit content of labels using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want a custom view (custom alert view) that extends its height in order to fit its subviews properly. I found similar questions but none of the suggested answers solved my problem. Any ideas how to achieve that? Is it possible to change superview's height dynamically using AutoLayout in this case?

**My nib file looks like this ...**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

By changing Red - Blue bottom constraint's priority to `Low`, the `container` follows label's size but superview still the same.

[image]

The `layoutIfNeeded` has no effect and when I am overriding `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, `UILabel` is not wrapping its content properly.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is what I have for now in order to achieve what I am looking for:

After setting `UILabel`'s text,

```
[redView layoutIfNeeded];
CGRect frame = redView.frame;
frame.size.height = 2 * padding + CGRectGetMaxY(greyLabel.frame);
redView.frame = frame;
```

This way I can adjust nib's height to match current label's height.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want your cell height to be dynamic to fit the label right? Here is my approach. Also you can take a look at this tutorial [self-sizing-cell](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/):

[image: this is my constrains for the label]

In your `viewDidLoad` method, add this code:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0f; 
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

and in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` configure the label:

```
cell.questionBodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.questionBodyLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.questionBodyLabel sizeToFit];
cell.questionBodyLabel.text = someLongText;
```

and you are good to go. Don't forget to delete the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`method, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The custom view I have is to be used as an alternative `alert view` not cell. There is no way to specify height or estimate height.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I made this in about an hour and it was created just for this question, it works like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:[CCHSCustomAlertView customAlertViewWithTextBody:tt title:@"This is an Alert!" andFrame:self.view.frame]];
```

Here's the code, give it a try:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CCHSCustomAlertView : UIControl

- (id)initWithTextString:(NSString*)string title:(NSString*)title andFrame:(CGRect)frame  NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
+ (instancetype)customAlertViewWithTextBody:(NSString *)text title:(NSString*)title andFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "CCHSCustomAlertView.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)

#define MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS 736.00
#define MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS 414.00

#define heightResizer(n) n/MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS*SCREEN_HEIGHT
#define widthResizer(n) n/MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS*SCREEN_WIDTH

@interface CCHSCustomAlertView ()
@end

@implementation CCHSCustomAlertView {
    UILabel * dismissAlertViewButton;
    UILabel * fakeLabelResizingWindow;
    UIView * fadedBackgroundView;
}

- (instancetype)initWithText:(NSString *)text title:(NSString*)title andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [self initWithTextString:text title:title andFrame:frame];
}

+ (instancetype)customAlertViewWithTextBody:(NSString *)text title:(NSString*)title andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [[self alloc] initWithTextString:text title:title andFrame:frame];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [self initWithTextString:nil title:nil andFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (id)initWithTextString:(NSString*)string title:(NSString*)title andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        fadedBackgroundView = [UIView new];
        [fadedBackgroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
        [fadedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
        [fadedBackgroundView setAlpha:0];
        [self addSubview:fadedBackgroundView];

        fakeLabelResizingWindow = [UILabel new];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:heightResizer(15)]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setTextColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setNumberOfLines:0];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setText:string];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setClipsToBounds:true];
        [[fakeLabelResizingWindow layer] setCornerRadius:3];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
        [self addSubview:fakeLabelResizingWindow];

        UILabel * header = [UILabel new];
        [header setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [header setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [header setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:heightResizer(20.0)]];
        [header setText:title];
        [header setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addSubview:header];

        UILabel * header1 = [UILabel new];
        [header1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [header1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [header1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:heightResizer(15)]];
        [header1 setNumberOfLines:0];
        [header1 setText:string];
        [header1 setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addSubview:header1];

        dismissAlertViewButton = [UILabel new];
        [[dismissAlertViewButton layer] setCornerRadius:3];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setText:@"Got It"];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:heightResizer(15)]];
        [dismissAlertViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addSubview:dismissAlertViewButton];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(header1, header, dismissAlertViewButton);
        NSDictionary * metrics = @{@"superViewHorizontalMarginOffset" : @(widthResizer(15.0)),
                                   @"buttonHeight" : @(heightResizer(44.0)),
                                   @"superViewVertMargOffset" : @(heightResizer(15.0))};

        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-[header]-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-|"
                                                                                        options:0
                                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                                          views:views]];

        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-[header1]-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-|"
                                                                                        options:0
                                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                                          views:views]];

        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-[dismissAlertViewButton]-superViewHorizontalMarginOffset-|"
                                                                                        options:0
                                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                                          views:views]];

        [fakeLabelResizingWindow addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-superViewVertMargOffset-[header]-superViewVertMargOffset-[header1]-superViewVertMargOffset-[dismissAlertViewButton(buttonHeight)]-superViewVertMargOffset-|"
                                                                                        options:0
                                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                                          views:views]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fakeLabelResizingWindow
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:SCREEN_WIDTH-widthResizer(60)]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fakeLabelResizingWindow
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:0]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fakeLabelResizingWindow
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:0]];

        [fakeLabelResizingWindow setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [fadedBackgroundView setAlpha:1];
            [fakeLabelResizingWindow setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ((CGRectContainsPoint([self frame], [[touches anyObject] locationInView:dismissAlertViewButton]))) {
        [dismissAlertViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ((CGRectContainsPoint([self frame], [[touches anyObject] locationInView:dismissAlertViewButton]))) {
        [dismissAlertViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ((CGRectContainsPoint([self frame], [[touches anyObject] locationInView:dismissAlertViewButton]))) {
        [dismissAlertViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [dismissAlertViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    if ((CGRectContainsPoint([self frame], [[touches anyObject] locationInView:dismissAlertViewButton]))) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [fakeLabelResizingWindow setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                [fadedBackgroundView setAlpha:0];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self removeFromSuperview];
            }];
        }];
    }
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

    @end
```

First off, to all the "LOLZ BUT YOU CAN'T DO THAT CUZ AUTO LAYOUT ISN'T SUPPOSE TO HAVE HARD CODED NUMBERS LOLZ", just don't, you don't know what you are talking about and you have no concept of how the auto layout engine works, so please feel free to move along and troll another Q/A scenario. So, now that this is out of the way, this works, for all iphone sizes, without having to do much more than change the font sizes (perhaps) and change the colors, corner radius, the font itself, etc, etc. you can even add a nifty button to the side like your Alert View nib has. The good thing about never doing anything in storyboards and nib files is that you have complete control over all elements in a relatively easy fashion. So, with that said, here's the logic:

I coded this without using a UIButton for the button because I didn't want to rely on any "one" particular UI element provided by UIKit, so, subclassing a UIControl and then smashing in other UI elements does the trick while allowing the user to use whatever UI element they want by adding their own touch gestures to said element or using the classes own touch handlers like I'm doing here. The blue "button" at the bottom of the view is a UILabel where the UIControl's touch events are considered "valid", all other touch events are ignored (see the logic in the touch event functions). The instances and initializers aren't at all necessary, I just did this because it's part of a much larger framework that I've created for my own private app build purposes and if it doesn't make sense to you, then just ignore it.

How this works: The label "fakeLabelResizingWindow" is a UILabel, I use a UILabel because I'm guaranteed to get the functionality of a resizing view accoding to text without having to do much more than what I'm doing here in this subclass. The best part about IOS is that you can use elements however you want in order to avoid nightmarishly long Sub class methods that do the same thing that another UI element from UIKit does. Why override drawRect when you can make UIKit do it for you without you needing to do much more than "guide" the standard elements into the correct formation to create a nifty little custom alert view.

You'll notice that all elements are resized using a resizing macro that makes resizing views super easy mode, program for an iPhone 6+ and nearly all your views will refit to the correct view of all iPhones without breaking layout contrataints. This allows you to do everything programatically basically just 1 time and everything flows through to fit for all iPhone devices. I've not given out my real method for making this happen, this macro is merely a small snippet of a much larger custom layout engine, but you get the idea.

The subviews of this UIControl are added to the "fakeLabelResizingWindow's" view as you can see, the fake label is added to the UIControl, constraints are added to allow a little flex of the outer "fakeLabelResizingWindow", but the inner guts of the three additional labels are constrained in a more stringent fashion. See the screen shots below for proof of concept, this auto resizes to fit the text. YOU MUST call the method by initilizing this custom alert view with a "frame", you can also customize this to the point where a single line call to this sub class allows you to change colors, fonts, font sizes, layers, etc, etc, the sky's the limit but you'll need to change the code of the subclass around and expose more of the variables as IVARs  to expose variables to the entire class architectures and method calls and in order to make this more "sassy".

Last but not least, this is a UIControl for many many many reason, I'm not going to go into a single reason why for my purposes here, but subclassing UIControls makes for some very neat things and good times in your apps.

Do good work, have fun, be safe, stay away from nibs and storyboards.

The proof of concept:

```
This is large alert view with a terrible wall of text
```

[image: This is large alert view with a terrible wall of text]

```
This is a smaller alert view with terrible text as well
```

[image: This is a smaller alert view with terrible text as well]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue.

I wanted to load a view from a nib (all the views inside the nib have proper constraints), set the width to fit the screen and let the height adjust itself to the content.

The solutions was this:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {

    var fitSize = UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize

    // this is the exact width that I want
    fitSize.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let size = systemLayoutSizeFitting(fitSize,
                                       withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh,
                                       verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel)

    // if you set horizontal priority to UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel, it will set the view size to fit the content, not the screen width

    frame.size = size
}
```